# Stuck in CodeIgniter Controller class implementation

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am recoding my site using CodeIgniter. This is my first time using an MVC or any other type of development pattern. I am using the video tutorials off of the CI site to make a playground and get acquainted with the protocol of the system.

I've just encountered my first problem and it has to do with a parent class.

I am on the second tutorial trying to make a blog and have this:

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function Test()
    {
        parent::CI_Controller();

        $this->load->scaffolding('entries');
    }

    function index() 
    {
        $data['muck'] = 'test test test';
        $data['kookoo'] = 'howdy howdy hi';
        $data['hi'] = 'holla';
        $data['yo'] = 'fa la la';
        $data['zoom'] = '1234';
        $data['array'] = array('hi','howdy','hey','sup');
        $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
    }

}

?>
```

When I loaded the page without the content inside the `function Test()` I noticed that the system could not find "Controller". I discovered that the tutorial is using an older version of CI and that "CI_Controller" is the proper name for the class Controller. Now with the above code I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::CI_Controller() in /Users/michaelsanger/Sites/CodeIgniter/application/controllers/test.php on line 7
```

I've scoured and am really not sure why it can't define it.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up things from different versions, the 1.7 one focusing mainly on PHP4-style class construction (using a method with the same name as the class as constructor, instead that the dedicated magic method __construct() available in php 5)

Also,  beware that *scaffolding is not present in the latest versions*. You didn't say which one are you using, I suppose V2. In case you're using an older version, 1) use the latest :) 2) the parent class was just Controller.

It should be like this

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();

         //$this->load->scaffolding('entries');
     }

     function Test()
     {
      // this will call a method name test, so maps to a URL like Test/test

     }

}
```

Note that it's not needed to extends the parent controller, unless of course you want to "autoload" a library to have it available to all methods.

CI is known for its great and easy documentation, so whenever you're using tutorial found on the net, expecially if a bit old (in internet terms), make an habit of going to the [**user_guide**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) (which is also shipped along with the installation files, for local browsing) whenever you have doubts or problems.

For example, check the [**controllers**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) page, you'll soon see what's wrong with your snippet (and the tutorial, as of today)

**UPDATE:**

In routes you're setting a route, that maps to a controller(/method).
Quoting the changelog:

> Version 2.0.0
>
> Release Date: January 28, 2011 Hg Tag: v2.0.0
>
> ```
> General changes
>
> PHP 4 support is removed. CodeIgniter now requires PHP 5.1.6.
> Scaffolding, having been deprecated for a number of versions, has been removed.
> ```

So I don't know what you mean now with scaffolding. Looking at your route, CI expects a controller named "scaffolding_trigger", which has to be rerouted to the controller "scaffolding". If any of those are present, you get the 404 error.
Please, choose a version and stick to that, don't mix things! and don't rely on tutorials, they're not always up-to-date with the latest changes.

Comment: fyi - I created scaffolding in the routes.php 
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "scaffolding";

Comment: and its giving me a 404 not found error now, which is better than before :)